# Unable to add custom authenticator account on Xiaomi Redmi

Tags: android, android-authenticator

I have developed an app that can add custom authenticator account. When I run this app on emulator I am able to add my custom account both way...
1. device setting -> Accounts -> add Account 
2. From my app

But when I run this app on Xiaomi Redmi 1S, I am unable to add account neither through device setting nor through my app.Actually, my authenticator service isn't called in this case.I don't know why? Do I have to include some other permissions?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. @mzr have you found any solution?

Comment: facing the same issue, any update?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did anybody resolve this?

Comment: I've the exact issue. Anybody from xiaomi?